# Replacing new line feed

Tags: python

I'm attempting to write extra text to the first line of this multi-line string using `replace`, and it doesn't work:

```
somestr = """For example
("""

print somestr.replace('\\n(', ' you can find')
```

I'm expecting the following result:

```
For example you can find
(
```

**Edit**

This string comes from a row object:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT col1 FROM tbl")
row = cursor.fetchone()
somestr = str(row.col1)
```

The output of `pprint.pprint(locals())` gives:

```
{'somestr': '\n\nFor example\n(\n'}
```

Comment: Beware with `str = str(row.col1)` That will only do something the first time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Don't escape the newline character* and it'll work just fine; do include the original text if you want to insert rather than replace:

```
somestr.replace('\n(', ' you can find\n(')
```

The original string does *not* contain the character sequence `\`, `n`, `(`, but your code is trying to replace just that. Instead, there is a newline character followed by `(` in that string, and to create the newline character you need to use `\n`, not `\\n`.

Demo:

```
>>> somestr = """For example
... ("""
>>> print somestr.replace('\n(', ' you can find\n(')
For example you can find
(
```

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work when the string comes from a row object. Can you see my edit?

Comment: @user3242205: given the exact output you printed, the `replace` works just fine. Be careful, don't use `str` as a local name, you are masking the built-in now.

Comment: Poor choice of name for the example. I still can't get it to work

Comment: @user3242205: what does `print repr(row.col1)` *for a failing value* produce? Make 100% certain that the value you are testing is one that fails for you.

Comment: Returns `u'\n\nFor Example\n(\n'`

Comment: @user3242205: again, the code works *fine* for that string. Are you sure you are not forgetting to *assign the return value of `str.replace()`?* The method returns the altered string, the value is not altered in-place as strings are immutable.